# JSFiddle Working But Files Aren't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my JSFiddle works but the files on my computer don't. Maybe they're not linking up or something that I overlooked? I already looked at the console but nothing pops up.

I'm super early into programming so any tips in the right direction would help me so much, thank you!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#show').click(function() {
        var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        $('body').css('background-color', color );
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #fff18e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       
    <title>Choose A COLOR!</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <button id="show">Surprise Me</button>
    
</body>
    
    
</html>
```

Comment: If there is nothing in console then try to debug line by line using ```console.log```. That will be hopefully helpful.

Comment: I guess, it's just a typo. When referencing your  `javascript.js`, you wrote `scr` instead of `src`. Maybe thatll solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is in the `javascript.js` file, then you need to place it in the `<head>` *after* you've included `jquery.js` as it relies on the `$` variable being already assigned. Also note that the attribute on the `script` tag is named `src`, not `scr`. Try this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped! I didn't know about that and I will keep that in mind going forward.